# Problems with type conversion - Pig -> HCatalog

Tags: load, apache-pig, hcatalog

I'm tryint to load table from HCatalog, do some exercises with data and store it into another table.

Source table: stage.iboa_event_definitions

```
inno_description  string    
inno_id           double    
inno_name     string    
inno_url      string    
inno_valid_from   string    
inno_valid_to     string
```

Destination table:

```
create table dictionary (id int,src_id double,source_code string, src_code string,     src_description string, group_code string);
```

My script:

```
iboa_event_definitions = LOAD 'stage.iboa_event_definitions' USING org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
iboa_event_definitions_filter = foreach iboa_event_definitions generate inno_id as src_id, 'IBOA' as source_code, inno_name as src_code, inno_description as src_description, '' as group_code;
iboa_event_definitions_filter_id = RANK iboa_event_definitions_filter;
final_table = foreach iboa_event_definitions_filter_id generate rank_iboa_event_definitions_filter as id:int, src_id, source_code as source_code, src_code, 
src_description, group_code;
store final_table into 'dictionary' using org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatStorer();
```

And I get error:

> 2013-11-26 13:18:06,140 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig features used in the
>   script: RANK 2013-11-26 13:18:06,143 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.rules.ColumnPruneVisitor - Columns
>   pruned for iboa_event_definitions: $3, $4, $5 2013-11-26 13:18:06,212
>   [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1115:
>   **Unsupported type: 10  in Pig's schema** Details at logfile: /export/home/pig/pig_1385463241554.log

Why? 
let's check field types.

```
describe iboa_event_definitions_filter_id;
iboa_event_definitions_filter_id: {rank_iboa_event_definitions_filter: long,src_id: double,source_code: chararray,src_code: chararray,src_description: chararray,group_code: chararray}

describe final_table;
final_table: {id: int,src_id: double,source_code: chararray,src_code: chararray,src_description: chararray,group_code: chararray}
```

Maybe the error is caused by Long type? But that's why I'm tryint to convert it into int.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Thanks

Pawel

Comment: My suggestion is to try to remove most columns to find the bad one. Also you may try to check docs/source to find what "10" means in "Unsupported type: 10 in Pig's schema"

Comment: I kwot what column is the problem -> the one that is created by RANK operation : rank_iboa_event_definitions_filter.

Comment: Correcttion: kwot -> know

Comment: facing same issue, did you resolved ?

Answer (score 3):

The key part of your error message is:

```
Unsupported type: 10 in Pig's schema
```

This occurred for me when I had an `INT` and tried to store it in a table where, where the corresponding column was a `BIGINT`.

The solution for me was to change the table (so not the Pig script), after which the store went well.

Answer (score 0):

Type 10 stands for Integer (see http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/api/constant-values.html#org.apache.pig.data.DataType.INTEGER). 
Your pig version does not support writing INT columns.

Use BIGINT as workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue when tried to store an int value [after casting to int] in a table where the corresponding column was a BIGINT.

**HIVE**

INT/INTEGER (4-byte signed integer)
BIGINT (8-byte signed integer)

**Corresponding in Pig**

int Signed 32-bit integer

long Signed 64-bit integer

So i cast my value to **long** and it solved my issue.